# How to retrieve URLs under a certain property using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve urls under a certain property. The current code I have is

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

url = 'https://play.acast.com/s/jeg-kan-ingenting-om-vin/33.hvorforercheninblancfraloireogsor-afrikaikkelengerpafolksradar-'
connection = urllib.urlopen(url)

dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
links = []

for link in dom.xpath('//meta/@content'): # select the url in href for all a tags(links)
    if 'mp3' in link:
        links.append(link)

output = set(links)

for i in output:
    print(i)
```

This outputs 2 links which is not what I want.

```
https://sphinx.acast.com/jeg-kan-ingenting-om-vin/33.hvorforercheninblancfraloireogsor-afrikaikkelengerpafolksradar-/media.mp3
https://sphinx.acast.com/jeg-kan-ingenting-om-vin/33.hvorforercheninblancfraloireogsor-afrikaikkelengerpafolksradar-r/media.mp3
```

What I would like to do is to get 'only' the URL link that is under `og:audio` property. Not `og:audio:secure_url` property.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only select a tag where the `property="og:audio"` and not `property="og:audio:secure_url"`, you can use an [`[attribute=value]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
CSS selector. In your case it would be: `[property="og:audio"]`.

Since you tagged [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup), you can do it as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(connection.read(), "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select('[property="og:audio"]'):
    print(tag["content"])
```

Output:

```
https://sphinx.acast.com/jeg-kan-ingenting-om-vin/33.hvorforercheninblancfraloireogsor-afrikaikkelengerpafolksradar-/media.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to study the XHR calls in the Network tab when you inspect the page. In the response of `https://feeder.acast.com/api/v1/shows/jeg-kan-ingenting-om-vin/episodes/33.hvorforercheninblancfraloireogsor-afrikaikkelengerpafolksradar-?showInfo=true` the url key is what you are looking for.